# A package for checking convergence in a MCMC sequence?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Does Mathematica have a package similar to [CODA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) in R, which tests for convergence of a sequence of parameter values obtained from a [MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) algorithm?
(A Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm is sometimes used when doing Bayesian Statistical Analysis of data, and we want to approximate the posterior distribution of the parameters.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I would assume it's Markov chain Monte Carlo, but still, some more details would be of use. It's a family of algorithms after all...

Comment: I am not aware of anything comparable (but that does not mean it doesn't exist ...)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm sorry about that. I've added some info and a link. ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Aaaah. Much better! =)